# Join 2 tables by closest time, PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, join, time

I have 2 tables: tbl1, tbl2.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(time_1)
AS VALUES
  ( '2017-09-06 15:26:03'::timestamp ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:26:02' ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:28:01' ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:40:00' );

CREATE TABLE tbl2(time_2)
AS VALUES
  ( '2017-09-06 15:29:01'::timestamp ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:40:00' ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:23:59' ),
  ( '2017-09-06 15:45:58' );
```

I want to join the table, thus for every row in tbl1 match closest time in tbl2. The output is :

```
     time_1                     time_2
---------------------      --------------------
 2017-09-06 15:26:03      2017-09-06 15:23:59      
 2017-09-06 15:26:02      2017-09-06 15:23:59 
 2017-09-06 15:28:01      2017-09-06 15:29:01
 2017-09-06 15:40:00      2017-09-06 15:45:58
```

I know how to find single value for closest time:

```
SELECT * from tbl1 where time_1=INPUT_TIME ORDER BY case when time_1 > INPUT_TIME then time_1 - INPUT_TIME else INPUT_TIME - time_1 end limit 1;
```

Comment: why doesn't `time_1=2017-09-06 15:40:00` join with `time_2=2017-09-06 15:40:00` where the difference is `0`?

Answer (score 10):

## Using `btree_gist` and `<->`

You really want `<->` which will actually work on GiST indexes through the internal `tstz_dist`. This works because you don't really care about the interval. First you need to add the extension,

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

then

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (time_1) time_1, time_2
FROM tbl1
CROSS JOIN tbl2
ORDER BY time_1, time_1 <-> time_2;
```

If there are too many rows to do a cross-join, you may have better luck with the lateral solution.

```
SELECT time_1, time_2
FROM tbl1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT time_2
  FROM tbl2
  ORDER BY time_1<->time_2
  LIMIT 1
) AS tbl2;
```

Would be interested in seeing a report back on the benchmarks. =) Especially if you have a GIST index on time_1 and time_2.

Comment: I followed your second approach and it works wonderfully! Reduces my particular query from 45s to around 2s

Answer (score 2):

Here's one attempt using a lateral join:

```
select time_1, time_2
from tbl1 
cross join lateral (
    select time_2 
    from tbl2 
    order by case when time_1 > time_2 then age(time_1,time_2) 
                                       else age(time_2,time_1) 
             end 
    fetch first 1 rows only
) as t;
```

Another possibility is to use a sub-query:

```
select time_1, (
    select time_2 
    from tbl2 
    order by case when time_1 > time_2 then age(time_1,time_2) 
                                       else age(time_2,time_1) 
             end 
    fetch first 1 rows only
)
from tbl1;
```

There is probably a more elegant way to determine the absolute value of the timestamp difference. Worth noting is that the result will be different if the order of the tables is changed.

Comment: See my answer for `<->`

Comment: @EvanCarroll, thanks, I tried it in @markp fiddle but it tells me `operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <-> timestamp without time zone`. Does it require that a GIST index is created?

Comment: updated my answer (you need to add the extension btree_gist)

Answer (score 1):

```
select dt1.time_1, 
       dt1.time_2 
from
(select row_number() over(partition by time_1 order by abs(extract('epoch' from time_1) - extract('epoch' from time_2)) asc) as rn,
        time_1,
        time_2
from    tbl1
cross
join    tbl2
) dt1
where dt1.rn = 1
order by dt1.time_1
```

- within the derived table `dt1` ...
- perform a `cross join` (aka cartesian product) across the 2 tables ...
- using the absolute value of the differences in `epoch` times to order row numbering for a group of rows with the same `time_1` value; then ...
- in the outer query limit our output to the first row (`dt1.rn = 1`) for each `time_1` value

Results:

```
time_1              | time_2             
------------------- | -------------------
2017-09-06 15:26:02 | 2017-09-06 15:23:59
2017-09-06 15:26:03 | 2017-09-06 15:23:59
2017-09-06 15:28:01 | 2017-09-06 15:29:01
2017-09-06 15:40:00 | 2017-09-06 15:40:00
```

NOTE: For the last `time_1 = 2017-09-06 15:40:00` we get a different `time_2` match than suggested in the question, which I'm assuming is incorrect:

```
-- suggested in the question:

     time_1                     time_2
---------------------      --------------------
 2017-09-06 15:40:00      2017-09-06 15:45:58
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4861bb6b4e367bf7d0d9945489a9d04c)