# Find a closest match in the same table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, timestamp

I have a table with timestamped data. For all the rows, I want to find the row that is the closest to 20 minutes after and between 15 and 25 minutes after.

e.g. if the table is like

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id,ts)
AS VALUES 
  ( 1::int, '2017.10.27T10:12:15'::timestamp with time zone ),
  ( 2,      '2017.10.27T10:24:17' ),
  ( 3,      '2017.10.27T10:30:22' ),
  ( 4,      '2017.10.27T10:40:12' ),
  ( 5,      '2017.10.27T10:52:16' ),
  ( 6,      '2017.10.27T10:53:11' );
```

I then run a query

```
 select t1.id as base t2.id as after
 from table t1, table t2 where ??
```

I would like to get the answer:

```
 base after
 1    3
 2    4
 3    5
```

For 4,5 and 6 as base I get no result as there are no rows matching with my criteria

It would be easy enough to get this for a given timestamp:

```
select id from table where timestamp > $mytimestamp+'00:15:00'
  and  timestamp < $mytimestamp + '00:25:00' 
order by 
   abs(extract ( epoch from (timestamp -($mytimestamp + '00:20:00'))) 
limit 1;
```

But how to do this for all the rows in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( ... LIMIT 1 )` to accomplish this, along with [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) and `<->`

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

SELECT f1.id AS base, f2.id AS after
FROM foo AS f1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id, ts
  FROM foo AS f2
  WHERE f2.ts BETWEEN f1.ts+'15 minutes' AND f1.ts+'25 minutes'
  ORDER BY f1.ts+'20 minutes' <-> f2.ts ASC
  LIMIT 1
) AS f2(id,ts);

 base | after 
------+-------
    1 |     3
    2 |     4
    3 |     5
(3 rows)
```

There are a lot of tricks going on here. We use `<->` as a distance operator for your *"closest to"*. Essentially, it can use a GiST index to determine this with KNN. We also use a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ... LIMIT 1` to get the list of all potential roles, and then limit it to just the one that is *"closest to"* as determined by our knn operator above.

This will work fastest with a gist index on `ts`.

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo USING gist ( ts );
```

See also [another question using `<->` on a time stamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185372/2639)